# Can a folder have multipe canonical paths to it?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I use a compute cluster with what I think is a fairly complicated filesystem setup so I would like to understand it.

There is a directory `foobar` and I can `cd` into it with

```
$ cd /a/b/foobar
```

If I enter the directory and run

```
$ readlink -f .
```

I get a path `/c/d/foobar` so `/a/b` is some sort of symlink. And if I do

```
$ cd /c/d/foobar
$ readlink -f .
```

I get `/c/d/foobar` so it is a canonical path.

Now there is another path `/e/f/foobar` such that if I run

```
$ cd /e/f/foobar
$ readlink -f .
```

I get `/e/f/foobar` so it is a canonical path as well.

In all three instances of `cd`, the `foobar` directory always has the exact same contents and the `foobar` directory is one that I created so I know what it contains. Is it possible that there can exist two different canonical paths to the same directory? Or is it more likely that the `/c/d` and `/e/f` are duplicates of each other on different drives?

Comment: It is possible to have two canonical paths. Symlinks can be reached by the same absolute path but this is not what is happening here. Easiest way to accomplish what you're seeing is to to have a bind mount or with a redundant network mount. Being on different drives is behind what you see. It might be interesting to run `df` while in each of the directories to see what device they're mounted on.

Comment: I think you're right. `stat /c/d/foobar` and `stat /e/f/foobar` show the same inode, but different device numbers. Does that mean there are two different physical devices mounted to the same path?

Comment: The are the same physical device mounted on two different paths. See @user10489 answer on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind mounts can create a second canonical path.

```
   mount -o bind /a/b /c/d
```

You can still use the `stat` command (or the syscall) to verify two items are the same item by comparing their device number and inode number.